# Fetching data in ionic

Tags: javascript, php, json, ionic-framework

I am trying to fetch data in my first ionic application from server but getting an error Cannot read Property attaching my code snippet. Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Component({
 selector: 'page-test',
 templateUrl: 'test.html'
})
export class TestPage {

 posts: any;

constructor (public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {

  this.http.get.('http://localhost/AppApis/salesheader.php').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(response => {

  console.log(response.object.object.object.cardname)});

}
)
```

Screenshot of Output:

[image]

Comment: Could you copy/paste your code into your question please? This makes it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the data like this.I hope that solves the problem

**service.ts**

```
  getdata() {

   var response = this.http.get('http://xxxxxx').map(res => res.json());
      console.log(response);
        return response;
```

}

**test.ts**

```
getdata:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public service:Service,public http : Http) {}

   this.service.getdata().subscribe(
                    data=>{

                   this.getdata = data;


                    });
```